# RDSAppXNotifyRecoveryTrigger on app deploy

Tags: windows-store-apps, visual-studio-2013

Simple question... Using Visual Studio 2013 to build and deploy A Windows Store App for Windows 8.1 with Javascript.  Unfortunately, even basic sample apps will not deploy.  The error that pops up everytime when attempting to deploy is `RDSAppXNotifyRecoveryTrigger`.

I cannot seem to find any information on this error which makes it very frustrating.  There is no problem when building the solution, however then we get the message...

`The app needs to be deployed.  When you click deploy we get this annoying ERROR: Error 1   Error : DEP0700 : Registration of the app failed. error 0x80070003: AppX Deployment operation failed. The specific error text for this failure is: RDSAppXNotifyRecoveryTrigger (0x80073cf9)`

So it would help if I could find anything on MSDN about this error unfortunately someone asked this same question and then the entire post was deleted from the forums. Please help, I have tried to repair my Visual Studio installation, since even when you open a brand new Template App and press F5 you get this error, so I am thinking something is wrong or corrupt in my environment that is preventing any type of Windows Store App deployments, I cannot even run the apps.  Thank you for any suggestions.

Answer (score 0):

The specific Error 0x80073cf9 is related to apps not being able to be installed with Windows Store.

Some users have been successful with any of these 2 solutions:

1: The problem is that the folder AUInstallAgent is missing from the Windows folder.

Press Win+R, in Run type %windir% and press Enter. Create new folder named AUInstallAgent if that is missing in the Windows directory. Reboot computer

2: Start Command Prompt with 'Run as Administrator' option.
run this command:

```
powershell -ExecutionPolicy Unrestricted Add-AppxPackage -DisableDevelopmentMode -Register $Env:SystemRoot\WinStore\AppxManifest.xml
```

Hope this helps.

I have the same problem and this did not work for me. Still found lots of comments that this worked for others.